# Vue: How to start a time countup from seconds?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that gets makes an API call when the component mounts and gets a time in seconds (example: 2313).  It is the only API call made so I want to take those seconds and convert it to a HH:MM:SS time and count up each second.  I assume I'll need to make a method that takes the seconds when the data comes in but I don't know what to do from that points.

```
mounted() {
    axios.get('')
    .then(response => {
        this.seconds = response.timeInSeconds;
    })
},
data: {
    return() {
         seconds: null,
    }
},
watch: {
    seconds(newVal) {
        if (newVal != null) {
              // ????
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a couple of things.

Firstly, you will need to use SetTimeout function to run every second, and when it runs it just increments your this.seconds property. This timeout function should be set in your ajax response, and it should call itself so it runs again. Thinking more about it, you are probably better to just use the current datetime value and calculate the difference as running the timeout function may get out of time, depends how long it will run for. Whereas taking the difference from the current time and the time it ran will let you know how many seconds to add, and it will be in perfect sync with the clock.

Secondly, you will need a computed function to take those seconds and convert it to HH:MM:SS. There are libraries for this, but you can just use a combination of modulus and remainder to calculate the hours and minutes. 3600 seconds in an hour (60*60) etc.